# Why is $( \alpha_i r_i) (\alpha_j r_j ) = \frac{1}{2} \{ \alpha_i , \alpha_j\}r_i r_j$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices, clifford-algebra

Where $\alpha_i= \left(
\begin{matrix}
0 & \sigma_i \\
\sigma_i & 0
\end{matrix}
\right)$.

To me it should just be $( \alpha_i r_i) (\alpha_j r_j ) = \alpha_i \alpha_j r_i r_j$, but it is not. Why the difference?

Comment: and what is $r_i$? Also, is summation over repeated indices implied anywhere?

Comment: $r_i$ is a constant. I am using Einstein notation.

Comment: For the Dirac $\gamma$ matrices in the Weyl representation (chiral) the off diagonal blocks have opposing signs. Did you purposefully omit it?

Comment: "To me it should just be..." Yep, that's also true, but perhaps the point is that the right-hand side is more convenient in certain cases.  This is an *identity*, not a *definition*. Why don't you just try to calculate both sides and see if they're equal?  (I did, assuming summation over repeated indices, and the two sides are the same, whether you include the negative sign suggested by lpz or not.

Comment: @Junjiro OK, now your expression makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $r_ir_j = r_jr_i$ we have
$$
(\alpha_i r_i) (\alpha_jr_j) = \alpha_i\alpha_j r_ir_j\\
= \frac 12 \alpha_i\alpha_j  r_ir_j + \frac 12 \alpha_i\alpha_j  r_jr_i\\
= \frac 12 \alpha_i\alpha_j r_ir_j +\frac 12 \alpha_j\alpha_i r_ir_j\quad \text{relabeling $i\leftrightarrow j$ in second term} \\
= \frac 12 \{\alpha_i\alpha_j\}  r_ir_j
$$

Answer (score 4):

Without loss of generality,

$$
\alpha_i \alpha_j = \frac{1}{2} \left( [\alpha_i, \alpha_j] + \{\alpha_i, \alpha_j\}\right) 
$$

Note the first term is antisymmetric under interchange of $i$ and $j$, and the second term is symmetric.

Second, note that $r_i r_j$ is symmetric under interchange of $i$ and $j$. Therefore, $[\alpha_i, \alpha_j] r_i r_j = 0$.

This follows since the trace of a product of an antisymmetric matrix and a symmetric matrix is zero. If $A=-A^T$, and $S=S^T$, then ${\rm tr}(AS) = {\rm tr} ((AS)^T) = {\rm tr}(S^T A^T) = {\rm tr}(A^T S^T) = -{\rm tr}(A S)$, and therefore ${\rm tr}(AS)=0$. In this chain of equations I've used ${\rm tr}(AB)={\rm tr}(BA)$, ${\rm tr}(A)={\rm tr}(A^T)$, $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$, and ${\rm tr}(-A) = - {\rm tr}(A)$.

Combining the above facts, we conclude that
$$
\alpha_i \alpha_j r^i r^j = \frac{1}{2} [\alpha_i, \alpha_j] r^i r^j + \frac{1}{2}\left\{\alpha_i, \alpha_j\right\} r^i r^j = \frac{1}{2}\left\{\alpha_i, \alpha_j\right\} r^i r^j
$$